# React MUI: theme color custom prop not applied

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styles, themes

I have 2 themes, dark mode and light mode:

```
import { styled, alpha, ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

//I use the dark theme only
const themeLight = createTheme({
... 
})

const themeBlack = createTheme({
    palette: {
        background: {
            default: "#262626",
            paper: "#262626"
        },
        primary: {
            main: "#FEB139",
            light: "#FEB139",
            dark: "#FEB139",
        },
        secondary: {
            main: "#143F6B"
        },
        tertiary: {
            main: "#FFBC80"
        },
        base: {
            main: "#F55353"
        },
        info: {
            main: "#FEB139",
            light: "#FEB139",
            dark: "#FEB139"
        },
        text: {
            default: "#FF9F45"
        },
        shadow: "rgba(118, 118, 118, 0.23)",
        mode: "dark",
    },
    typography: {
        body1: {
            color: "#FF9F45"
        },
        h1: {
            color: "#FF9F45"
        },
        h2: {
            color: "#FF9F45"
        },
        h3: {
            color: "#FF9F45"
        },
        h4: {
            color: "#FF9F45"
        },
        h5: {
            color: "#129F65"
        },
        h6: {
            color: "#FF9F45"
        },
    },
    root: {
        color: "#F55353"
    },
    card: "#111111",
    top: "#1E1E1E",
    line: "#111111",
    title: {
        font: "'Lato', sans-serif",
        size: 22,
        weight: 600,
        color: "#FEB139",
    },
    gradient: "linear-gradient(274deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,#FEB139 0%, #F55353 100%)",
    maxPadding: 80,
    minPadding: 10,
    drawerWidth: 240,

});

export { themeLight, themeBlack };
```

On some pages, it works fine, but on some specific ones it doesn't. The problem aappears generally on all components, but I will focus right now on typography.

```
<Typography variant="h4">
    Login
</Typography>
```

As you might see, in the theme object, `#FF9F45` is the specified color, but for some reason it is not applied. Checking the styles using the Chrome dev tools, the color seems to be overridden by the default one [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component/page had another theme nested inside:

```
const theme = createTheme();

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
...
</ThemeProvider>
```

The mui basic templates include separate themes for each component, so thats how it got there.